# How to parse json array with Newtonsoft.Json?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Please help me to parse array from this json in C#:

```
{
        "error_code":0,
        "response":
        {
            "17":
                {
                    "id":"17","name":"Books"
                },
            "21":
                {
                    "id":"21","name":"Movies"
                },
            "13":
                {
                    "id":"13","name":"Cafe"
                },
            "5":
                {
                    "id":"5","name":"Music"
                },
            "49":
                {
                    "id":"49","name":"Theatres"
                }
        }
    }
```

I'm using the Newtonsoft.Json library

Comment: That is not an array, its an object which properties are named with strings which happens to be numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a JSON array - it's just a JSON *object* which happens to have numbers for the properties of the `response` object.

You can parse it as a `JObject`, or deserialize it to a class like this:

```
public class Root
{
    public int ErrorCode { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Entry> Response { get; set; }
}

public class Entry
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

...

Root root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
```

Comment: Thanks, Jon! When I renamed the ErrorCode to "error_code" and Entries to "response" in Root class, then it worked!

Comment: @dvlpr: `Entries` should have been `Response`, but that should be all you need - I'd expect Json.NET to map error_code to ErrorCode. If it doesn't, you can always apply appropriate naming attributes.